# Hide/Encrypt application configuration

Tags: security, configuration, encryption

Is there any way to hide/crypt software config files (services such as Apache web server , Varnish and so on) from boss and others?

Comment: "Others" including people with root access to the server?

Answer (score 0):

You might use an encrypted filesystem. Fooling around with encryption of the configuration, and get the users (all of them!) of said configuration to have the key and use it is a daunting task... and `root` can relatively easily bypass this. Also have to intercept and doctor all updates to the system...

Doing this is a clear indication you want to hide something... and *that* might get you into hot water.

Better secure the machine against unauthorized access, and keep an eye on it.